# How to capture contents provided by script into form ASP.NET MVC submission?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have tried to get around this but can't seem to get it. I have two models and one with collection that reference the other. I want to create the collection together with the model that reference it but for some reasons the collection is always empty after form submission.

```
public class Plays
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string? GameName { get; set; }  
     public List<GamePlay> GamePlays { get; set; }
}
```

I want to  add gameplay in the create page/method of plays

```
public class GamePlay
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Power { get; set; }
     public int PlaysId { get; set; }
     public Plays? Plays { get; set; }
}
```

and in my Create.cshtml

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
      <form asp-action="AddNew" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
         <div class="form-group">
              <label asp-for="gameName" class="control-label"></label>
              <input asp-for="gameName" class="form-control" />
              <span asp-validation-for="gameName" class="text-danger"></span>
          </div></br>         
          <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" value="Create games-Play" class="btn btn-primary" />
          </div>
      </form>
  </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <!-- Your content goes here -->
        <!-- Hidden input fields for GameName and Selection -->
        <input type="hidden" id="HiddenGameName" name="GamePlays[0].Power" />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Power">Power:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Power" />
                </div>
            </div>          
            <div class="col-md-2 align-self-end">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="button" value="Add GamePlay" class="btn btn-primary reset" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <input id="Items" name="Items" hidden="hidden" />
        </div> </br>



        <table id="dataTable" class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Power</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @if (Model.GamePlays != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in Model.Power)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@item.Power</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#" class="edit">Remove</a>
                            </td>
                          
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

The table gets filled with script so that I see the collections and also populate it in same page but when I click on the submit button, the collection suddenly becomes empty.

I use the below script to populate the table. I don't think its the issue but I will still put it here for more clarity..

```
<script>
    // Serialize the model to JSON using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert
    var modelJson = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.GamePlays));
    $(document).ready(function () {
   
        $(document).on("click", ".reset", function () {
            var gameName = $("#Power").val();

            if (gameName && selection) {
                var row = "<tr><td>" + gameName + "</td><td>" + selection + "</td><td><a href='#' class='edit'>Remove</a></td></tr>";
                $("#dataTable tbody").append(row);

                // Add to the model collection
                var item = { GameName: gameName, Selection: selection };
                modelJson.push(item);
                $("#Items").val(JSON.stringify(modelJson));
                // Update hidden input fields
                $("#HiddenPower").val(modelJson[modelJson.length - 1].Power);
                // Clear input fields
                $("#Power").val("");
            }
        });      
    });
</script>
```

Please help me out, if I set a breakpoint at the client Create method, I see that the gameplay collection is always empty but its not empty before submission. I have also tried to put the table in the enclosed tags of the form but its still same problem.

Comment: You do understand that the submit button will only submit the `<input>` tags that are between `<form>` and `</form>`, right?  Nothing in the "col-md-6" div is going to be sent.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have tried that but same thing but let me follow another approach and will get back to you on my results if it went well or not

Comment: @TimRoberts i have done that but now i am getting just one item in the collection instead of the many items i inserted

Comment: I don't see a `name` in your `id-"Power"` tag.  The `name` determines how it gets sent.

Comment: Hi @Alva Mira, how do you define `@model` in Create view? It seems not be neither Plays or GamePlay model. Also what is the `selection` in your js code? And you can see there is only one input element with name `gameName` in the form, but you want to receive the List<GamePlay> in the backend, it is impossible because your model even does not have such property.  You can only post the data inside the form to backend and the element in form should be input or textarea or selectlist etc.  The table td or span type element cannot be posted to backend by form submit.